# Customize table name of hyperjaxb3 generated entity?

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I'm having an xml schema where have simpleType(**diagnosisCode**) as shown below:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MedicalClaimDetail">
    <xsd:element name="diagnosisCode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>   
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This has generated a top level class with one-to-many relation ship to a child class as:

A parent class with original property and a transient property to hyperjaxb generated class:

```
@Entity(name = "MedicalClaimDetail")
@Table(name = "A_ES_MED_CLM_DETAIL")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class MedicalClaimDetail
    implements Serializable, Equals, HashCode
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> diagnosisCode;

    protected transient List<MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem> diagnosisCodeItems;

    @Transient
    public List<String> getDiagnosisCode() {
        if (diagnosisCode == null) {
            diagnosisCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.diagnosisCode;
    }

    public void setDiagnosisCode(List<String> diagnosisCode) {
        this.diagnosisCode = diagnosisCode;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "DIAGNOSISCODEITEMS_MEDICALCL_0")
    public List<MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem> getDiagnosisCodeItems() {
        if (this.diagnosisCodeItems == null) {
            this.diagnosisCodeItems = new ArrayList<MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem>();
        }
        if (ItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.diagnosisCode)) {
            this.diagnosisCode = ItemUtils.wrap(this.diagnosisCode, this.diagnosisCodeItems, MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem.class);
        }
        return this.diagnosisCodeItems;
    }

    public void setDiagnosisCodeItems(List<MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem> value) {
        this.diagnosisCode = null;
        this.diagnosisCodeItems = null;
        this.diagnosisCodeItems = value;
        if (this.diagnosisCodeItems == null) {
            this.diagnosisCodeItems = new ArrayList<MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem>();
        }
        if (ItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.diagnosisCode)) {
            this.diagnosisCode = ItemUtils.wrap(this.diagnosisCode, this.diagnosisCodeItems, MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem.class);
        }
    }
```

Child class as:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity(name = "MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem")
@Table(name = "MEDICALCLAIMDETAILDIAGNOSISC_0")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem
    implements Serializable, Item<String>
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "diagnosisCode", namespace = "http://vo.edge.fm.cms.hhs.gov")
    protected String item;
    @XmlTransient
    protected Long hjid;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ITEM", length = 30)
    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String value) {
        this.item = value;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "HJID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getHjid() {
        return hjid;
    }

    public void setHjid(Long value) {
        this.hjid = value;
    }

}
```

Now the question: Is there a way to customize the table name of the auto-generated entity :**MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem** which is hyperjaxb generated table name as MEDICALCLAIMDETAILDIAGNOSISC_0

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this resolved. See the code below to customize the table name of generated entity/class using external binding:

```
    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="xsd/medicalClaim/MedicalClaimDetail.xsd"
        node="/xs:schema">

        <jaxb:bindings
            node="xs:complexType[@name='MedicalClaimDetail']//xs:element[@name='diagnosisCode']">
            <hj:generated-class
                className="MedicalClaimDetailDiagnosisCodeItem">
                <hj:entity>
                    <orm:table name="A_ES_MED_CLM_DTL_DG_CD_ITM" />
                </hj:entity>
            </hj:generated-class>
        </jaxb:bindings>

    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

HJ3 has a lot of cutomization options.

For examples, see the following project:

https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/cu-one/src/main/resources

Comment: Thank you !!.. I used the same sample which helped to resolve.